# Why doesn't astype timedelta64 work on ndarray?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, casting, timedelta

Why does `.astype('timedelta64[D]')` fail to cast the `ndarray` in the following example?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=5, freq='W'), columns=['Val'])
df['Base'] = pd.datetime(2015, 1, 1)
df['Days'] = (df['Val'] - df['Base']).astype('timedelta64[D]') # Success
df['FailCast'] = (df['Val'].values - df['Base'].values).astype('timedelta64[D]') # Failure

print (df)

         Val       Base   Days   FailCast
0 2017-01-01 2015-01-01  731.0   731 days
1 2017-01-08 2015-01-01  738.0   738 days
2 2017-01-15 2015-01-01  745.0   745 days
3 2017-01-22 2015-01-01  752.0   752 days
4 2017-01-29 2015-01-01  759.0   759 days
```

Especially considering that it will successfully cast the values when applied as a separate operation after the fact: E.g.,

```
df['FailCast'] = df['FailCast'].astype('timedelta64[D]') # Success!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact the case you are calling "success" is actually the one that seems out of sorts.  It is a `float64` not the requested `timedelta64`.

#### Why?

Why is it a `float64`?  Because of the method:

```
pandas.dtypes.cast.astype_nansafe()
```

in which appears this line:

```
result = arr.astype(dtype).astype(np.float64)
```

This path is invoked because this line:

```
(df['Val'] - df['Base']).astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

invokes: `NDFrame.astype`, where as this line:

```
(df['Val'].values - df['Base'].values).astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

invokes `numpy.ndarray.astype()`.

The difference is due to the different types in the intermediate products.

#### Bottom Line:

Calling `astype()` on a numpy array differs in behavior from `astype()` on a pandas Series.

#### Test Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=5, freq='W'),
                  columns=['Val'])
df['Base'] = pd.datetime(2015, 1, 1, 12)
df['Days'] = (df['Val'] - df['Base']).astype('timedelta64[D]')  # Success
df['FailCast'] = (df['Val'].values - df['Base'].values).astype(
    'timedelta64[D]')  # Failure

print(df)
print(df.dtypes)
```

#### Results:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

         Val       Base   Days FailCast
0 2017-01-01 2015-01-01  731.0 731 days
1 2017-01-08 2015-01-01  738.0 738 days
2 2017-01-15 2015-01-01  745.0 745 days
3 2017-01-22 2015-01-01  752.0 752 days
4 2017-01-29 2015-01-01  759.0 759 days

Val          datetime64[ns]
Base         datetime64[ns]
Days                float64
FailCast    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Actually, I'm a bit lost.

Comment: Yes, it looks like it has done something.  But why is the `astype` call producing a different result in the "FailCast" case than the result in I'm calling "Success" in the `'Days'` column?

Comment: If anything I would argue that "success" is the weird one, as it is a float64, not the requested timedelta64.  I will do a bit more research to see what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Good point!  I only know enough to observe that something appears to be wrong; I hope you can illuminate it!

Answer (score 2):

Note that these are equivalent:

```
df['FailCast'] = df['FailCast'].values.astype('timedelta64[D]')
```

And

```
df['FailCast'] = np.array([731, 738, 745, 752, 759], dtype='timedelta64[D]')
```

By passing `.astype(int)` after you get same output.

Comment: So it appears that the "FailCast" examples have *sort of* made the conversion, but not *all the way*?  I can't tell whether this is a superficial quirk in the text/view output layer, or how deep it goes....